# `render` shows stale model value, while redirect_to shows the correct one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given that `A has_many B`, I update some attributes of model B in a given method of A's controller.

If at the end of this method I call

```
    render action: 'show'
```

, the old values (i.e. prior to the update) will be rendered. If instead I do

```
    redirect_to @a
```

, the correct/updated value will be shown.

**What could be causing this behavior? Is there a method for explicitly marking a model as 'updated'?**

Comment: Can you post your show and update methods.

Comment: Have you initialized both @a and @b in the update method? If you are calling @b.save, it would not reload @a which is being passed to the render method.

Comment: That was the issue indeed - I was calling `B.new({a_id: a.id})` but then the @a object receives no notification. Not sure if this caveat is common to all ORMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by reloading object

```
@a.reload
```

before the `render action: 'show'`